# Firebird: Unable to complete network request to host

Tags: firebird, remote-server

I'm trying to connect to a remote Firebird database "test" (alias already added). It is not an embedded server, and is installed on VM with IP 192.168.1.147.

Here is my connection string:

> User=sysdba;Password=masterkey;Database=test;DataSource=192.168.1.147

However I got an error:

> FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException (0x80004005): Unable to complete network request to host "192.168.1.147". ---> Unable to complete network request to host "192.168.1.147".

I've done some research on that but haven't got a clue yet. Some help needed. Thanks

---

My IP address is 192.168.2.108, and I can ping that server IP successfully

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make sure that

1. Firebird is running
2. Firebird is listening on port 3050 on the specified IP (or on 0.0.0.0)
3. Your firewall allows access to port 3050
4. You're using the correct host name

Comment: yeah. and the port is changed to 3051 somehow..tx

Comment: Hi, I same this the problem and I checked 1,2,3 yours steps but I still canot connect to firebird.
Unable to complete network request to host "localhost".
   at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionInternal.Connect() in c:\Users\fer\Desktop\firebird-NETProvider-f021ee8d2569dbd22cabbe3a3f1e656fc7e6672f\NETProvider\src\FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient\FirebirdClient\FbConnectionInternal.cs:line 196
   at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection.Open() in c:\Users\fer\Desktop\firebird-NETProvider-f021ee8d2569dbd22cabbe3a3f1e656fc7e6672f\NETProvider\src\Firebird..

Comment: My problem appear after I uninstall Kaspersky. Can you help me ?

Comment: @LukeLe Check the default Windows firewall if Firebird is allowed to accept incoming connections on port 3050. If not, add it. Otherwise I suggest you take this to the firebird-support mailing list.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thank for reply. I checked in WF and it allowed. but i still connect to db. 
I also use IBExpert to connect to DB, when I choose Server/Protocol is' Local, default' it work fine, but when i choose Server/Protocol is 'Remote, TCP/IP' with localhost and port fbserver running, then Connection failed!
This problem just appear after install and uninstall Kaspersky internet security 2017.

Answer (score 7):

For Linux, the Firebird port is closed by default. You need to modify `RemoteBindAddress` in `/etc/firebird/2.5/firebird.conf` from

```
RemoteBindAddress = localhost
```

to

```
RemoteBindAddress =
```

and restart service.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have excluded tcp port 3050 in VMs' firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I think your connection to firebird is faililing because the firebird client looks up the network service file by name and does not find gds_db in the services file.
If your connection string refers to the host by using IP, the Client might fail to identify it because it gethostbyname() and not by IP
Manually include this in the file and you should be fine.
C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\services