# Firebird ISC ERROR CODE:335544721

Tags: delphi, firebird

We have had this error recently reported by our clients and we on't know how we can fix this. We are using Delphi XE6 to develop our application and it connect to Firebird (v2.5) database as back-end. We also have used IBObjects for working with Firebird database in Delphi.
We have managed to replicate the error on the dev machine by stopping Firebird windows service before running a query but we haven't found a way to detect the connection lost in the code (e.g. by having an event) so as we don't know when this happens so we cannot reconnect to the database in the code either.

By the way, this is full error message if it helps:

ISC ERROR CODE:335544721
ISC ERROR MESSAGE:
Unable to complete network request to host "BON-VFS-01".
Error writing data to the connection.

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22338165/firebird-unable-to-complete-network-request-to-host

Comment: @RBA It sounds more like the connection gets closed in the middle, so most of the points in the answers to that question don't apply. It could be a firewall terminating long running TCP/IP connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From IBOBjects [FAQ](http://www.ibobjects.com/ibo_faq.html)

> Is there a way to detect a lost connection and try to reconnect
>   automatically, without user action?
>
> Hook into the OnError event and look for the ERRCODE that denotes a
>   lost connection. Then, you can take whatever action you deem necessary
>   to deal with the problem. If the connection is lost you need to do a
>   disconnect and then connect again.

And from one of the base members of the IBObjects:

> However, perhaps the "something" you are missing is that, if the
>   connection  is broken by an external cause, the client application has
>   no way to know  that it is not still connected. Its first knowledge of
>   that fact will come  the next time it tries to access the server. The
>   API will report  "Connection lost to database" and return GDSCODE
>   335544741, which is  identified by the constant
>   isc_lost_db_connection.
>
> At the point where this exception occurs, the TIB_Connection still
>   thinks  it is connected - the Connected property will be true. If you
>   try to  reconnect by calling Connect, you will get an IBO exception.
>   It is  necessary to call Disconnect. This does not simply reset a
>   property. The  Disconnect method performs all of the necessary cleanup
>   to invalidate the  broken transactions and cancel any now invalid
>   postings, datasets and  caches. Once Disconnect has completed its
>   work, you can then place a  Connect call inside a retry loop and
>   attempt to get going again.
>
> I do not know of a working example, but the simplest way to deal with
>   this  is to write a RestoreConnection handler procedure that you can
>   call from  your IB_Session.OnError handler whenever argument ERRCODE
>   returns  isc_lost_db_connection.
>
> Have your RestoreConnection procedure do whatever you need to do,
>   trying to  call Connect and handling the exception that occurs if the
>   request fails,  until no exception occurs. Test the Connected property
>   after each  iteration. When Connected is finally True, you are in
>   business. You can  drop out of the retry code and inform the user that
>   the connection has been  restored - perhaps with a sound and/or a
>   message in the status bar, to  avoid having to show a dialog box that
>   she has to respond to. (if you like  the idea of sound and status bar
>   cues, you could devise "connection lost"  warning sound and status bar
>   message code to run at the beginning of your  handler procedure as
>   well...)
>
> If these broken connections are a frequent occurrence, you might like
>   to  consider making a distinctive custom cursor that you can display
>   while your  procedure is running, and enclose the retry code in a
>   non-yielding  BeginBusy...EndBusy block with UseCursor enabled and
>   BusyCursor set to use  this special cursor image.
>
> And if re-establishing a connection is likely to take a long time, or
>   to be  temporarily impossible, you would need to provide the ability
>   for the user  to intervene and choose not to keep trying. You can use
>   the session timer  for this, enclosing your "busy" block inside
>   another iterative block the  prompts the user to "Cancel" or "Keep
>   Trying", at reasonable intervals.

[Source](http://www.codenewsfast.com/cnf/article/0/permalink.art-ng2076q36591)

Answer (score 0):

Check out if their database file is located on mapped network drive. Even if database file path appear to be local to file system, when using embedded Firebird server, function isc_attach_database will return error code 335544721 on attempt to establish connection. Exactly that was happening on my VirtualBox guest Windows XP when I first share entire host D drive and then mapped it again as D drive in virtual guest OS.

Workaround will be to move database file to local partition drive.

Answer (score 0):

check your query length

max query length is 8191 chars UTF-8

its solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

connect your pc to the internet, and the problem will be fixed,but i don't how it works

Comment: It would be more helpful if you took a further step by looking up the error code and giving a more detailed answer. Good Job though by making your first post on the platform.